# Python run-script-phase in Xcode no longer working

Tags: python, python-3.x, xcode

I have an Xcode run-script-build phase that triggers a python script. Before Xcode 13.3 it worked, but now it doesn't any more. I know that Apple ditched python 2 and therefore I have to change a bit of my script to work with python 3. I can not run my script from the console, but not Xcode.

My script requires e.g.

```
import requests
```

which I installed using `pip3`.
Xcode now is complaining about that module not being there:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

My script phase in Xcode looks like the following:

```
if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" = "Release" ]; then
    python3 MyScript.py
fi
```

And again... running the same command -> `python3 MyScript.py` directly in my console works.

Comment: Are you sure that XCode is using the same installation of Python that is being run on the command line?

Comment: Yes... that seems to have been the problem. I changed it by giving the whole path to python 3 (which was in the brew directory) and then it worked... thx